# Second part of where clause in sql/vba has

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I'm using vba, to combine entries in an sql database into 5 minute ranges into excel, ive noticed oddly that the code below would always pull in entries only until approx 9:15pm (from 12:00:0am)  Checking the database there are plenty of entries after (9:15pm)

I've narrowed this down to the second part of the WHERE clause "AND [DateTime]<= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')+28, 0)"  which doesn't seem to work, at all, separating it out or running it on the SQL server directly doesn't work

but just replacing the <= with a >=  (without the other half of the where query) and it runs the query as expected

so I'm obviously missing something simple but not seeing it, thanks for the help :-x

```
selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDbConn
   selectCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') as Date_Time " & _
    " ,max(Part_Count)-min(Part_Count) as PartsMade" & _
    ", max(Alarm_Light) as Alarmlight" & _
    ", max(PV_Alarm) as Alarm" & _
    " FROM [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport] " & _
    " Where [DateTime]>= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')-0, 0) AND [DateTime]<= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')+28, 0) " & _
    " AND Machine_Number = " & Machvar & " " & _
    " Group BY DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') "
```

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95d1b3809ea2d29c2f4a4e4becbd6da7) shows no real unexpected output, as far as i can tell.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind three things

1. The only rare thing that if I see in your code is '+28' the end date interval if I do a test with that +28.

The result adds 28 hours more to your interval and for this reason after 9pm it affects your query (add one day).

```
declare @dat as datetime=DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '2020-02-15 20:59:00')+28, 0)
declare @dat2 as datetime=DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '2020-02-15 21:00:00')+28, 0)
print (@dat)
print (@dat2)
```

result is

```
Feb 17 2020 12:00AM
Feb 17 2020  1:00AM
```

2. I recommend using **between** the two dates with hours, minutes and seconds

   ```
   select DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') AS INTERVAL,
   max(Part_Count),min(Part_Count),max(Alarm_Light) as Alarmlight,max(PV_Alarm) as Alarm 
   FROM TestImport
   WHERE DateTime between '2020-02-15 21:00:00' AND '2020-02-15 21:20:00'
   Group BY DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101')
   ```

The date must be calculated in the Excel sheet and sent in format (YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS) or if it is a full day without time and at the end date +1

3. Generates the query by replacing values ​​and not joining strings

   ```
   Dim Querysql as String
   Querysql = " 
   select DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') AS INTERVAL,
   max(Part_Count),min(Part_Count),max(Alarm_Light) as Alarmlight,max(PV_Alarm) as Alarm FROM TestImport
   WHERE DateTime between '${FechaIni}' AND '${FechaFin}'
   Group BY DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5
   "
   Replace(Querysql, "${FechaIni}", 2020-02-15 21:00:00)
   Replace(Querysql, "${FechaFin}", 2020-02-15 21:20:00)

   exec comand
   ```

To avoid SQL injection validate input value equals date and with maximum length.

[my test data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9d3a5/43)

Comment: ah interesting, yes the idea was to grab the 24 hours containing the day and only those 24 hours, but your way of doing it seems a lot cleaner!